# Magento 2 I want to display login form in shopping cart page

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, checkout, cart

how I can add Login form in the shopping cart page?

[image]

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Go to

> Admin>Stores>configuration>Sales>Checkout

Set **Allow Guest Checkout** to "**NO**"

Comment: you check this? becuase on my store is not work...

Comment: what you recommend just made this to appear as modal after press the Proceed to Checkout button, but I need to display them by default in the Shopping Cart page. You have any idea? If not please remove this answer. Thank you